# DataTable getting deformed after the update from Axios get call

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatable, axios

I have a data table for which I am doing an Axios get call and populating the tbody. As per observation, it is getting deformed (pagination not working, also if new data is just 10 rows, it shows 100 row. [Before update of 10 rows it was 100 rows so somehow data table not getting reinitialized])

This is my JavaScript which is updating tbody

```
<pre>
    <script>
        var sitename = "{{data.site.name | safe}}"
        var avm = document.getElementById("ravm");

        function loadAvm() {
        axios.get('ravm', {
            params: {
                site: sitename
            }
        }).then(function (resp) {
            console.log(resp.data.length);
            avm.innerHTML = resp.data;
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err)
        })
    }
        setInterval(function () {
        loadAvm();
    }, 3000);
    </script>
</pre>
```

My Django template is below

```
{% for key, value in data.alerts.items%}
<tr>
    <td class="text-{{value.severity}}">{{value.timestamp}}</td>
    <td class="text-{{value.severity}}">{{value.message_text}}
    </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

PS: Everything is working fine if I don't do this Axios call to update and just refresh pages to get new data from the view.

Answer (score 0):

after a lot of research i was able to find my answer

```
 table = $('#example1').dataTable();
         oSettings = table.fnSettings();

         table.fnClearTable(this);
         table.DataTable().destroy();
         table.find('tbody').append(resp.data);
         table.DataTable({
         "responsive": true,
         "autoWidth": false,
         "ordering": false,
         "info": true,
         "pageLength": 10,
         "bDestroy": true,
         "recordsFiltered": 10,
      }).draw();
```